# Container running but cannot be visited in browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I followed http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-compose.html and have a running container.

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting flaskcomposedockerexample_web_1
Attaching to flaskcomposedockerexample_web_1
web_1  |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
web_1  |  * Restarting with stat
web_1  |  * Debugger is active!

$ docker logs d66ca374c99a
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 249-821-232
```

Going to browser or curl will not connect:

```
This site can’t be reached

127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

$ curl 127.0.0.1:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
```

Why would a container with no errors not be able to be visited?

```
$ netstat 
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0      0  142.25.150.89.57766    stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED

tcp4       0      0  142.25.150.89.56837    8.36.126.32.http       ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.56800        localhost.56800        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.56801        localhost.56801       ESTABLISHED


$ docker inspect d66ca374c99a
[
    {
        "Id": "d66ca374c99afb13a2bee56fa44fd73f4c39569edcf8c50f175bf5a124a57a73",
        "Created": "2017-04-18T14:08:54.859932607Z",
        "Path": "python",
        "Args": [
            "app.py"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 14402,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-04-18T14:09:28.342011012Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:1b3ceada8dd91e8a4403e7ee001b7a4832f72120162f8788651c3301f5ccfa89",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/d66ca374c99afb13a2bee56fa44fd73f4c39569edcf8c50f175bf5a124a57a73/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/d66ca374c99afb13a2bee56fa44fd73f4c39569edcf8c50f175bf5a124a57a73/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/d66ca374c99afb13a2bee56fa44fd73f4c39569edcf8c50f175bf5a124a57a73/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/d66ca374c99afb13a2bee56fa44fd73f4c39569edcf8c50f175bf5a124a57a73/d66ca374c99afb13a2bee56fa44fd73f4c39569edcf8c50f175bf5a124a57a73-json.log",
        "Name": "/flaskcomposedockerexample_web_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/Users/cchilders/flask_compose_docker_example:/code:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/cchilders/flask_compose_docker_example",
                "Destination": "/code",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "d66ca374c99a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "app.py"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "flaskcomposedockerexample_web",
            "Volumes": {
                "/code": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "python"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "3c65c28cc5926f591068f82a4d028ae50573b14ac4059ebe17b196be2185995a",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "flaskcomposedockerexample",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "web",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.11.2"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "6b4cd91f76cb21f70fc7b1b17e403f21ef790cc1e02fee5547740ac5192229fe",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/6b4cd91f76cb",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "e05d8bf26815734a146d6f4b1fb803b365629dfce732a2b21993970a33e54a80",
            "Gateway": "162.16.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "162.16.0.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:bd:55:00:04",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "2fd3c33ec08105cd00de10ab5555554572bac4548866239aa375e8df60ed3aa",
                    "EndpointID": "e05d8bf26815734a146d6f4b1fb80555559dfce732a2b21993970a33e54a80",
                    "Gateway": "162.16.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "162.16.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:44:00:04"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]



$ netstat -tnlp
netstat: option requires an argument -- p
Usage:  netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
    netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
    netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgRtS]
    netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
    netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
    netstat -m [-m]
    netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
    netstat -rs [-s]

$ netstat -tnpl
netstat: l: unknown or uninstrumented protocol
```

Comment: Is it listening? Check via `sudo ss -tnpl | grep 5000`.

Comment: none of these commands work on mac. -tnpl fails for netstat and ss isnt found by homebrew

Comment: Oh, this is in a dev environment? In that case, it's off-topic here. I'll migrate to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. First the tutorial you are referring to has syntax error in the first line of  app.py, it should be

```
from flask import Flask
```

Secondly, Docker works differently in Mac and Windows. Docker doesn't directly map the ports to the local host; instead of that Docker creates a very small Linux virtual machine which is approximately 24 mb in size and then run containers inside that this virtual machine which is also called docker machine. So instead of mapping the ports to localhost, Docker maps it to docker machine so your containers should be accessible to

```
http://docker_machine_ip:port_no
```

Instead of

```
http://localhost:port_no
```

The default docker machine IP address can be found using:

```
 docker-machine ip dev
```

Comment: Post the output of netstat -tnlp

Comment: yes the tutorial has an error, I fixed that and the docker container is running, but my machine isnt listening to any docker ports

Comment: can you try running some other container like nginx docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx:latest

Comment: All containers fail to connect

Comment: `$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
ddee48dc6ecc        nginx:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   frosty_neumann
c55c9169046a        metricsportal-test   "python metricspor..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp          objective_galileo
`

Comment: `cchilders:~/flask_compose_docker_example 
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
`

Comment: I think on osx docker doesn't work directly it runs inside a Linux VM so you can't directly access the docker containers with the host ip you have to find your docker-machine ip with this command docker-machine ip default so first you have to create docker machine then connect to it and then create containers inside it .

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: I don't know what to do for that. I already did the `eval $(docker-machine env default)` thing earlier to get docker to start

Comment: You need to find your docker machine with this command  docker-machine ip dev after that you will be able to access your containers like http://dockermachineip:5000

Comment: In Mac and windows you can't directly access the docker containers suppose your docker machine ip is 192.168.0.2 then you can access your containers like 192.168.0.2:5000

Comment: ok you wanna change your answer to explain finding the default ip?

Comment: Hey I have edited the answer if the problem is solved you can mark it as solved thanks in advance